# How to filter and display image with respect to text in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to display flag image from asset folder with respect to country code which I am getting in API response.

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="details_container" *ngFor="let contacts of keycontact">
    <img src="../../../../assets/images/flags/usa.jpg" class="logo">
    <p class="name_font font_white">{{contacts.purpose}}</p>
    <p class="name_font font_white">{{contacts.contactNumber}}</p>
</div>
```

**Componen file :-**

```
ngOnInit(): void {

  //initialize
  this.keycontact = this.keyContactService.getKeyContacts()

    //Subscribe
    this.keyContactService.updatedkeyContacts.subscribe((contacts)=>{
      this.keycontact = contacts
      console.log(this.keycontact);
    })

    // Api Call
    this.keyContactApis.fetkeyContDetails();
  }
```

**response as :-**

```
    {
                "id": 28,
                "purpose": "HR related queries",
                "contactNumber": "+1 201-350-8620",
                "contactPerson": "Abhishek  Kaashyap",
                "location": "NA",
                "employeeSubsidiary": "LLC",
                "region": "US",
                "workCity": "US",
                "beforeFlip": "NULL",
                "initials": "HR"
            },
{
                "id": 29,
                "purpose": "HR related queries",
                "contactNumber": "+91 995-350-8620",
                "contactPerson": "Abhishek  Kaashyap",
                "location": "NA",
                "employeeSubsidiary": "LLC",
                "region": "IND",
                "workCity": "IND",
                "beforeFlip": "NULL",
                "initials": "HR"
            }
```

The response is dynamic with more objects.How I can pick `region` key and check text = US or IND or more other countries and accordingly pass flag image path in the `<img>` in HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular Intepolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) just how you did in your p tags:

`<p class="name_font font_white">{{contacts.purpose}}</p>`

so your img tag can look something like this:

`<img src="../../../../assets/images/flags/{{contacts.region}}.jpg" class="logo">`

### Edit

With [Property Bindng](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax) you can dynamically get your file with a method:

`<img [src]="getFlag(contacts.region)" class="logo">`

and in your .ts file declare a method:

```
public getFlag(region: string): string {
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: No actually this is not the case. In the response I am getting `{{contacts.region}}`. So in HTML how will I do some logic like if region will be 'usa' then from asset folder us flag image will be picked , if region will be 'india' then Indian flag image path will pick from assets folder..same goes for other countries dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a constants file with the mappings and fetch the url using that.

constants.ts

```
class Constants

public static flagImageNames = {
    'usa': 'us',
    'can': 'can',
    ...
}
```

ts

```
public flagNames = Constants.flagImageNames;
```

html

```
<img src="../../../../assets/images/flags/{{flagNames[contacts.region]}}.jpg" class="logo">
```